# Ruby set default package version

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems, installation, uninstallation

I have 2 json gem version: 1.8.1 and 1.8.0.
The 1.8.1 is the default version and i need to **remove it** and **set** the **1.8.0** as **default version**.

This is the `gem list` output:

```
...
json (default: 1.8.1, 1.8.0)
...
```

I tryed to execute `sudo gem uninstall json -v 1.8.1` and the output was:

```
gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo gem uninstall json -v 1.8.1 --force`

Comment: Yeah same thing for me